# wrong output with for-loop in OPENMP

Tags: for-loop, openmp

hi Im newbie in OpenMp and have a problem with simple for-loop. well this is my code:

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <omp.h>

   char str[20];
   INT64 i;

   int main()
   {
   HANDLE hAppend;
   DWORD dwBytesToWrite ,dwPos;
   DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
   hAppend = CreateFile(L"log.txt" , 
   GENERIC_WRITE, 
   0, // do not share
   NULL, 
   OPEN_ALWAYS, 
   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
   NULL); 

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(i)
   {
    #pragma omp for ordered 
    for( i=0; i<=MAXINT64;i++)
    {     

sprintf(str,"%x | %x \r\n",i);
    dwPos = SetFilePointer(hAppend, 0, NULL, FILE_END);

    LockFile(hAppend, dwPos, 0, strlen(str), 0);
    WriteFile(
          hAppend,
          str,
          strlen(str),
          &dwBytesWritten,
          NULL 

             );
      }
     }
    }
```

and this is part of the output:

```
1ee5 | 60000000 
1ee6 | 60000000 
1ee7 | 60000000 
1ee8 | 60000000 
1ee9 | 60000000 
1eea | 60000000 
0 |  | 60000000 
0 | 40000000 
1eed | 600000001 | 40000000 
2 | 40000000 
1 | 40000000 
1eee | 60000000 
1eef | 60000000 
1ef0 | 60000000 
1ef1 | 60000000 
3 | 40000000 
1ef 40000000 
4 | 40000000 
2 | 0 
3 | 0 
4 | 0
```

with out open mp everything is ok but whith parallelism 
outputs become wrong.whats wrong with OpenMp?or my code?

Comment: There might be problem using openmp and lock/write to file and also not declaring str private in for loop

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the "ordered" clause with the for construct, are you trying to run parts of the parallel "for" loop in an ordered fashion?

If you use "ordered" on the "for" construct to serialize parts the loop (the access to the file?), you also need an "ordered" construct inside the loop body to tell the compiler which part of the parallel loops has to be executed ordered:

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
for(...) {
  // something that runs parallel
  do_parallel();
  // serialize
#pragma omp ordered
  {
     do_ordered();
  }
}
```